# How to pipe output of tmux pane to vim/neovim?

Tags: vim, tmux

I have neovim open in one pane, and I have `ipython` open in another pane. I have set up keymappings which allow me to send keys or to paste my buffer in my ipython pane without leaving neovim.

I'm trying to now set up a keymapping to have the output of my ipython session piped directly to my neovim buffer. I've tried `pipe-pane` and `capture-pane` but I cannot get it working.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple script to copy buffer contents to a file. You can modify it to open in neovim

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

tmux capture-pane -pJS - > /tmp/tb
tmux display "Saved to /tmp/tb"
```

You can create a key binding by adding below to tmux config

```
bind c run-shell /path/to/tmux-capture.sh
```

`crtl+b+c` will run the script and save it to /tmp/tb